# Remove mongodb document fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am wanting to update my document structure wherein I wish to remove particular fields based on value.

```
"id" : "company",
"keys" : {
    "0" : {
        "key_name" : "Name",
        "section_head" : "Profile"
    },
    "1" : {
        "key_name" : "Sector",
        "section_head" : "Profile"
    },
    "2" : {
        "key_name" : "SubSector",
        "section_head" : "Profile"
    }}
```

I want to delete from keys where key_name is Subsector and id is company.

Comment: is it necessary to have numbers as key in your document structure? As content(key/structure) of all numbers is same, It seems there is not need to use numbers as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the indexes your solution should be something like:

```
var doc = db.myDoc.find({_id : "company"});
var keys = [];
for (var key in doc) {      
    if (doc.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.key_name === "SubSector"){
        keys.push(key);
    }
}

var arrayLength = keys.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     delete doc[keys[i]];    
}

db.myDoc.save(doc);
```

That is the main problem when you are using dynamic keys inside a `MongoDb document`

Of course you can optimize this solution but it's left for you (-:

--- EDIT ---

```
db.eval(function () {
   db.myDoc.find({id: "company"}).forEach(function (e) {
      var keys = [];
      for (var key in doc) {
         if (doc.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.key_name === "SubSector"){
             keys.push(key);
         }
     }

     var arrayLength = keys.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
         delete doc[keys[i]];
     }

     db.myDoc.save(doc);
     });
});
```

Comment: Ya this is one solution....i have already done something similar using php but it would be great if u could give me a mongo query to do the same

Comment: updated. gl and please don't forget to vote up if i've helped you